# How to get (split) filenames from string in java?

Tags: java, string, file

I have a string that contains file names like:

```
"file1.txt file2.jpg tricky file name.txt other tricky filenames containing áéíőéáóó.gif"
```

How can I get the file names, one by one? 
I am looking for the most safe most through method, preferably something java standard. There has got to be some regular expression already out there, I am counting on your experience.

Edit: expected results:
"file1.txt", "file2.jpg", "tricky file name.txt", "other tricky filenames containing áéíőéáóó.gif"

Thanks for the help,
Sziro

Comment: Can you show ho you expect the filenames to be split? Can space be part of the filename? Do files always end in known extension(s)?

Comment: as you can see space can be part of the name "tricky file name.txt" and "other tricky filenames containing áéíőéáóó.gif"

Comment: If your files don't necessarily end in some extensions and they contain space too, it won't be possible.

Comment: all files end with an extension ?

Comment: You can't. How would you tell between "tricky file name" and "tricky file name"? (the first is three files, and the second is one file)

Comment: Will there ever be dots in a file name, other than for the extension?

Comment: Probably one dot per filename, at the extension. But you know, users are tricky..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expresion that enrico.bacis suggested *(\S.*?.\S+)* will not work if there are filenames without characters before "." like *.project*.

Correct pattern would be:

```
(([^ .]+ +)*\S*\.\S+)
```

You can try it [here](http://regex101.com/r/eU2uW6/1).

Java program that could extract filenames will look like:

```
String patternStr = "([^ .]+ +)*\\S*\\.\\S+";
String input = "file1.txt .project file2.jpg tricky file name.txt other tricky filenames containing áéíoéáóó.gif";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {            
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Yes, better, it covers more cases. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions you can find all the occurrences of:

```
(\S.*?\.\S+)
```

(you can test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/uW1aR5/1))

Comment: How can I use it in java?
String[] attachmentFiles = attachmentDisplay.split("(\\S.*?\\.\\S+)"); does not return the correct answer.

Comment: split does not use regular expressions, you can check how to use regex in java here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: He uses it like me. EXAMPLE_TEST.split("\\s+")

Comment: Lo! It works. the correct method is String[] attachmentFiles = attachmentDisplay.split("(\\s.*?\\.\\s+)"); Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String txt = "file1.txt file2.jpg tricky file name.txt other tricky filenames containing áéíőéáóó.gif";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S.*?\\.\\S+"); // Get regex from enrico.bacis
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group().trim());
    }
```

Comment: It would not give back "tricky file name.txt", only "name.txt".

Comment: @Sziro now I used regex and fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces in the file names, it makes it trickier.

If you can assume there are no dots (.) in the file names, you can use the dot to find each individual records as has been suggested.

If you can't assume there are no dots in file names, e.g. my file.new something.txt

In this situation, I'd suggest you create a list of acceptable extentions, e.g. .doc, .jpg, .pdf etc.

I know the list may be long, so it's not ideal. Once you have done this you can look for these extensions and assume what's before it is a valid filename.